# "ImportError: cannot import name 'set_curdoc' from 'panel.io.state'"

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, python-import

I was working with the widgets from the panel library and all of a sudden I was no longer able to import the library.

I installed with

```
pip install panel
```

and imported the library like

```
import panel as pn
pn.extension()
```

I keep getting this error code:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'set_curdoc' from 'panel.io.state'  
(/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/panel/io/state.py)
```

Anybody knows why?

Answer (score 0):

please try with this in your terminal:
`conda install -c pyviz panel`